# EDGE laggy in showing keyboard input

Tags: javascript, html, performance, delay, microsoft-edge

The code below, when executed by edge shows a lot of input lag.
Steps to reproduce:

1. copy paste the snippit in a local html file.
   It will not be reproducable from the snippit editor in stackoverflow.
2. open it with edge
3. make sure auto fill form fields are ON in edge settings/advanced . there is no need to actually have these form fields
4. slam your keyboard with random keys  (more than 10 keys/sec)
   it's a bit rude but necessary to demonstrate. On a production page where there is css, normal typing is enough to see the issue.
5. Not sure if it matters, Version where this issue works
   Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
   Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

You will see the input still being filled in even if you already stopped slamming the keyboard.

Workaround found but not acceptible for our situation

1. Disable "save form entries" option in edge. (not acceptable as we cannot force all our users to do this)
2. remove form element (obviously not acceptable)

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="decimal" id="OrderLines_0__AmountExcl" name="OrderLines[0].AmountExcl" type="text" value="45,00" /></td>
                    <td><input class="decimal" id="OrderLines_0__VAT" name="OrderLines[0].VAT" type="text" value="21,00" /></td>
                    <td><input class="decimal" id="OrderLines_0__Quantity" name="OrderLines[0].Quantity" type="text" value="1,00" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_0__Unit" name="OrderLines[0].Unit" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_0__ReductionPercentage" name="OrderLines[0].ReductionPercentage" type="text" value="" /></td>
                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_1__AmountExcl" name="OrderLines[1].AmountExcl" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_1__VAT" name="OrderLines[1].VAT" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_1__Quantity" name="OrderLines[1].Quantity" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_1__Unit" name="OrderLines[1].Unit" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_1__ReductionPercentage" name="OrderLines[1].ReductionPercentage" type="text" value="" /></td>
               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_2__AmountExcl" name="OrderLines[2].AmountExcl" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_2__VAT" name="OrderLines[2].VAT" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_2__Quantity" name="OrderLines[2].Quantity" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_2__Unit" name="OrderLines[2].Unit" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_2__ReductionPercentage" name="OrderLines[2].ReductionPercentage" type="text" value="" /></td>
                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_3__AmountExcl" name="OrderLines[3].AmountExcl" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_3__VAT" name="OrderLines[3].VAT" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_3__Quantity" name="OrderLines[3].Quantity" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_3__Unit" name="OrderLines[3].Unit" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_3__ReductionPercentage" name="OrderLines[3].ReductionPercentage" type="text" value="" /></td>
                  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_4__AmountExcl" name="OrderLines[4].AmountExcl" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_4__VAT" name="OrderLines[4].VAT" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_4__Quantity" name="OrderLines[4].Quantity" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_4__Unit" name="OrderLines[4].Unit" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_4__ReductionPercentage" name="OrderLines[4].ReductionPercentage" type="text" value="" /></td>
               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_5__AmountExcl" name="OrderLines[5].AmountExcl" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_5__VAT" name="OrderLines[5].VAT" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_5__Quantity" name="OrderLines[5].Quantity" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_5__Unit" name="OrderLines[5].Unit" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_5__ReductionPercentage" name="OrderLines[5].ReductionPercentage" type="text" value="" /></td>
             
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_6__AmountExcl" name="OrderLines[6].AmountExcl" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_6__VAT" name="OrderLines[6].VAT" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_6__Quantity" name="OrderLines[6].Quantity" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_6__Unit" name="OrderLines[6].Unit" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_6__ReductionPercentage" name="OrderLines[6].ReductionPercentage" type="text" value="" /></td>
               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_7__AmountExcl" name="OrderLines[7].AmountExcl" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_7__VAT" name="OrderLines[7].VAT" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_7__Quantity" name="OrderLines[7].Quantity" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_7__Unit" name="OrderLines[7].Unit" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_7__ReductionPercentage" name="OrderLines[7].ReductionPercentage" type="text" value="" /></td>
                
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_8__AmountExcl" name="OrderLines[8].AmountExcl" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_8__VAT" name="OrderLines[8].VAT" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_8__Quantity" name="OrderLines[8].Quantity" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_8__Unit" name="OrderLines[8].Unit" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_8__ReductionPercentage" name="OrderLines[8].ReductionPercentage" type="text" value="" /></td>
              
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_9__AmountExcl" name="OrderLines[9].AmountExcl" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_9__VAT" name="OrderLines[9].VAT" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_9__Quantity" name="OrderLines[9].Quantity" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_9__Unit" name="OrderLines[9].Unit" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input id="OrderLines_9__ReductionPercentage" name="OrderLines[9].ReductionPercentage" type="text" value="" /></td>                  
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edge performance profiler shows big delays on the input event
[image: 100msdelay]

And pins it to the AutoFormFill extension which is by default enabled in Edge

[image: Autoformfill js]

Detailed overview getFormIdentifier

[image]

Detailed overview Isimple iloop

[image]

Comment: Have you tried if the `autocomplete="off"` attribute would help?

Comment: Yes, on form level, input level and I also tried to add a non existing "list"

Comment: Are you able to see the source for that `iSimple`/`i` function within the extension? Maybe you're hitting some sort of edge (pun intended) case (e.g. I could imagine with the names of your fields having brackets) it's bad at.

Comment: @akX I've updated the post with the detailed trace

Comment: I am using the exact same version of Edge. https://i.postimg.cc/vHCVsfZr/27.png I try to refer your steps and try to run your code in Edge. Here is the output. https://i.postimg.cc/Nf2KpFk5/27.gif Note that auto fields are On while testing. In my result, You can see that I am not able to produce the issue. Let me know, If I missed something from your above description. I will try to correct myself.